# textarea&div wont clear onclick

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

function html(el) {
    var html = el.value || '', 
    wysiwyg = document.getElementById('output_html');

    if (html == '') {
    document.getElementById('clear').disabled = true;
    html = 'HTML editor!';
    } else {
    document.getElementById('clear').disabled = false;
    }

    wysiwyg.innerHTML = html;
}
function clear() {
    var html = document.getElementById('input_html'), 
    wysiwyg = document.getElementById('output_html');

    wysiwyg.innerHTML = 'HTML editor!';
    html.innerHTML = '';
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="javascript:document.getElementById('clear').disabled = false;">
    <div id="output_html">HTML editor!</div>
    <input id="clear" type="submit" onclick="clear()" value="Clear"/>
    <textarea id="input_html" onKeyUp="html(this)" placeholder="Type HTML!"></textarea>
</body>
</html>
```

I wanted to learn JavaScript and fool around with it, but I came across a problem.

When I type things on the textarea, it auto updates as i want it to.

When I press on "Clear" it should clear, but it wont. Why is it doing this?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165570/is-clear-a-reserved-word-in-javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortest answer is don't use inline handlers. These run with document scope, so it will try to run `document.clear()` before going up one more level and finding the global `window.clear()`, which is your function.

```
window.onload = function() {

    document.getElementById("input_html").onkeyup = function () {
        var html = this.value || '', 
        wysiwyg = document.getElementById('output_html');

        if (html == '') {
            document.getElementById('clear').disabled = true;
            html = 'HTML editor!';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('clear').disabled = false;
        }
        wysiwyg.innerHTML = html;
    }

    document.getElementById("clear").onclick = function () {
        var html = document.getElementById('input_html'), 
            wysiwyg = document.getElementById('output_html');
        wysiwyg.innerHTML = 'HTML editor!';
        html.value = '';
    }
}
```

HTML:

```
<body>
    <div id="output_html">HTML editor!</div>
    <input id="clear" type="submit" value="Clear"/>
    <textarea id="input_html" placeholder="Type HTML!"></textarea>
</body>
```

Comment: whoa, did not expect to be so complicated.

Comment: Yea - and Stephen's comment about value instead of innerHTML.

Answer (score 0):

Long story short, you want to set the **value** of the textarea, not its innerHTML.