# Why Can't I Use JS Function Called 'evaluate' in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm kind of curious why this doesn't work

JavaScript:

```
function evaluate(){
    console.log(42);
}
```

HTML:

```
<a onclick="evaluate()">Click Me!</a>
```

Is evaluate a reserved keyword somewhere on the html side?

Comment: Interesting. Chrome does not show anything, but Firefox throws `NS_ERROR_XPC_NOT_ENOUGH_ARGS: Not enough arguments`. This could be because of two different reasons though.

Comment: That's very strange. I thought it was an alias for eval() but I can call that function using eval. See this http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GFEow. I don't know why I can't call evaluate() directly either. I too think it might be a reserved keyword or something.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is "clear" a reserved word in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165570/is-clear-a-reserved-word-in-javascript)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`document.evaluate` is needed for parsing XMLs, see [the reference in the MDN here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Introduction_to_using_XPath_in_JavaScript).

Comment: Another relevant fact is that event handlers are run `with` the document and target node's properties pulled into scope.

Comment: @Mike: Do you have a reference for that?

Comment: @FelixKling, 19.1.6 of http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/webprog/jscript/ch19_01.htm .  You can see this at work in `<input type=button value=MyButton onclick="alert(value)">`

Comment: @Mike: Thanks! And now that you mention it, I remember that I have seen this before. It's just strange that I cannot find anything in any specification.

Comment: @FelixKling, Yeah.  From that book, "The precise composition of the scope chain has never been standardized and is implementation-dependent. Netscape 6 and Mozilla include all containing objects (even things such as `<div>` tags), while IE 6 sticks to a more minimal set that includes the target element, plus the containing Form object (if any) and the Document object."  That level of disagreement is hard to codify after the fact.

Answer (score 3):

"evaluate" is not a reserved keyword, but when it's used in **inline** event handler, it happens to collide with document's `evaluate` function(`document` object is within handler's scope chain **before** the `window` object). If you don't want to change your function name, just add `window` context before it, i.e.

`<a onclick="window.evaluate()">Click Me!</a>`

Answer (score 3):

Evaluate is not a [reserved word](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words) in JavaScript, [`document.evaluate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.evaluate) is used to evaluate [XPath](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPath) expressions.

You could still name your function `evaluate` if you used a less obtrusive method of attaching your event handler:

```
var evaluate = function (){
    console.log(42);
}

document.addEventListener('click', evaluate, false);
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/RWRdJ/)