# Javascript onclick call function doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, html

I have my textarea, when it is clicked upon I would like the text to clear

```
<textarea id="cow" rows="5" name="message" cols="50" onfocus="clear()" >Please provide a link to an image no wider than 500px. </textarea>
```

and the javascript from external js file:

```
var cow=document.getElementById("cow").value;
function clear(){ document.getElementById("cow").value=' '; }
```

I realize I could probably use Jquery, but I'm just messing around trying to learn javascript.

Comment: is your closing </textarea> tag really like that, or is that a copy paste error? also, try actually using onclick instead of onfocus

Comment: @LifeInTheGrey JacobM biffed it in the edit.

Comment: If you want to learn JavaScript, [start with some lessons](http://nathansjslessons.appspot.com/). Even the minimal code you've written here is already poorly constructed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Believe it or not, your code is ok, apart from the fact that you named the function **`clear`**.

Inside inline event handler, the `document` object is hooked up into the event handler's scope chain, in *some* browsers. This has the unfortunate effect that `clear` does not refer to your function, but to [`document.clear`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/document.clear). This behavior is not standardized, so depending on which browser you use, you might see different results.

If you **rename your function**, it works just fine: http://jsfiddle.net/QqMsX/.

---

You should definitely read "[Is "clear" a reserved word in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165570/is-clear-a-reserved-word-in-javascript)", where I also explained how to avoid such situations.

Comment: I tested that `document.clear === clear` within the handler. Can you explain what you mean by "the document object is hooked up into the event handler's scope" The scope is the `this` element, right? But there's no usage of `this` in the handler. It's like there's a hidden `with (document){}` around that handler.

Comment: No, with "scope" I mean all the variables that are accessible inside a function. `this` is not scope.... `this` is just `this` :) Just like `window` is part of a functions scope chain (global variables), `document` is inside the scope chain of inline event handlers.

Comment: That's why I asked for clarification; however, many people call `this` the `scope` of a function (not that it's correct). I do see now that you're talking about scope chain (which is what a `with(document){}` does)

Comment: Thanks for well researched answer!  I always like to know the whys behind any answer.

Comment: Thanks for fixing my problem Felix

Comment: @Isaac: You're welcome! Don't forget to accept the answer that helped you the most by clicking on the checkmark next to it.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the browser is trying to call `document.clear` instead of the clear function you created. If you rename your function to `clearText`, it works fine http://jsfiddle.net/7meL7/

A good way to avoid the problem is to avoid JS in attributes altogether

```
<textarea id="cow" rows="5" name="message" cols="50">Please provide a link to an image no wider than 500px. </textarea>

// There are better ways, but this is the simplest crossbrowser way
document.getElementById("cow").onfocus = function() {
    this.value = '';
}
```

Comment: Odd they both work for me even though I tried that in my own fiddle! That my only complaint about JavaScript is it's quirkiness between browser :-) I'm going to research, I bet clear is a reserverd word somewhere in a name space.

Comment: @defaultNINJA: Have a look at my answer and the question I linked to.

Comment: @defaultNINJA Yes the linked answer explains it really well