# Why isn't my button function clear() working?

Tags: javascript, html

Any particular reason why my button isn't working when I click on it? Here's the code.

```
    <script>
    function save() {
        if (isNaN(document.form.result.value) || document.form.result.value == 0) {
        document.getElementById('hours').innerHTML = "There was an input error, make sure that: <br> The calculator field is not empty <br> Only include numbers as an input";
        document.getElementById('hoursdiv').style.background = "yellow";
        } else {
        savedvalue = document.form.result.value;
        document.getElementById('hours').innerHTML = "Hours Worked This Week: " + savedvalue;
        document.getElementById('hoursdiv').style.background = "";
            }
    }
    function clear() {
        alert("hi");
    }
   </script>

    <div>
    <!-- Save Button -->
<input class = "customSubmitButton" type="button" onClick="save();" value="Save">

   <!-- Clear Button -->
<input class = "customSubmitButton" type="button" onClick = "clear()" value = "Clear">

    <div id = "hoursdiv">
        <p>
           <strong id = "hours"> </strong>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Save button works just fine.

Comment: do you get any errors? cons

Comment: `save` is working but `clear` doesn't?

Comment: Save works just fine, but clear doesn't. Doesnt show me the alert.

Comment: @mad_programmer, yes first thing I tried.

Comment: `clear()`, if I'm not wrong, is the function that clears up the console

Comment: Ya, the person who has written the answer below and LightStyle is right as well..clear() shouldnt be used. Its a reserved name.

Comment: Any documentation for `clear` being reserved? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165570/is-clear-a-reserved-word-in-javascript

Comment: Not reserved, just predefined and taking precedence in the scope chain.

Comment: No, it's not **reserved**, is just already assigned. It's like if you're assigning it again, it's strange it doesn't work but it can be that it is defined after the user functions. Anyway, for a list of **reserved** keywords please refer to this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try changing the name of your function.

[Is "clear" a reserved word in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165570/is-clear-a-reserved-word-in-javascript)

Comment: "clear is not a reserved keyword": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165570/is-clear-a-reserved-word-in-javascript

Comment: Javascript console says: `document.clear() is deprecated. This method doesn't do anything.`