# my function "clear()" is not getting called

Tags: javascript, html

I have a function called `clear()` that gets called when a button in my form gets clicked.
JS function:

```
function clear() {
  console.log("clear");
  document.getElementById("feet").value = '';
  document.getElementById("meters").value = '';
}
```

HTML:

```
<button onclick="clear();return false;">Clear</button>
```

When I click on the Clear button, the clear() function doesn't get called, any ideas why?

Comment: have you wirte your function inside `script` tag

Comment: yes its inside a script tag

Comment: Could you post more code or create a jsfiddle displaying the issue?

Comment: See [Is “clear” a reserved word in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165570/is-clear-a-reserved-word-in-javascript)

Comment: why are you using `clear();return false;`, why not include it in your function?

Comment: Call it anything other than `clear` if you want to invoke it like this.

Comment: yup it was because i called it clear, thanks guys

Comment: @JasonBoggess, a better solution would be to avoid inline javascript in the first place, [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/zbqXN/1/) or even [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/zbqXN/2/) if you want to use the name `clear()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try not using clear(), use another name as @j08691 quoted.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you use return false in there But ithink if you try using it like this

`<button onclick="_clear()">Clear</button>`

it will work

Comment: return false stops the browsers default behavior:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/128923/whats-the-effect-of-adding-return-false-to-an-onclick-event

Comment: Oh i see, i thought return false do nothing here, looks like there is something wrong with the document.getElementById("feet").value = '';

Answer (score 0):

You can't use clear as the name of the function ([Is "clear" a reserved word in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165570/is-clear-a-reserved-word-in-javascript)).  The problem is only when you try to call clear from within the document context which shadows the global window context.  Change it to _clear and it will work.

```
function _clear() {
  console.log("clear");
  document.getElementById("feet").value = '';
  document.getElementById("meters").value = '';
}
```

HTML:

```
<button onclick="_clear();return false;">Clear</button>
```

Comment: clear is NOT a reserved word.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FReserved_Words

Comment: Huh, I renamed the function _clear, tested it, and it worked so I just figured it was a reserved word.  I didn't even go look it up.  Let me change my post, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @Brian You can use `clear` as the name of a function. You're wording is still incorrect. The problem is only when you try to call `clear` from within the `document` context which shadows the global `window` context. For example: `window.clear(); return false;` would work just fine (note that I do not recommend either the use of global functions or scripts inside HTML attributes).

Comment: OK. . . I did say THE function, but you're right it's not clear enough, pun intended.  I'm going to steal your wordage and put it in, thanks.

Comment: Thanks to all for the comments

Comment: The question remained, what does "document.clear() do".  Here it is: "The Document.clear() method does nothing, but doesn't raise any error."                 (From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/clear which goes on to say Deprecated: This feature is no longer recommended...)    Apparently it only serves those in need of being confused.

Answer (score 0):

The clear() method comes only within the document context and it is deprecated method. We can't use in this context. You can use _clear() or any other alternative method name.