# clear text input by clicking on it

Tags: javascript

I've got `input` with `text` type. I want to clear it when I click on it.
However my approach does not work

```
<span class="input"><input type="text" id="input1" onclick="clear()"></span>
```

Where `clear()` function is

```
function clear() {
    alert(event.target.id);
    event.target.value = "";
}
```

What is the correct way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

function name `clear` [does not seem to be working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165570/is-clear-a-reserved-word-in-javascript). `Change the function name` (say, clearMe) and try (**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/H86JN/2/)**):

```
<script>
    function clearMe(x) {
    x.value = "";
}
</script>
<span class="input">
   <input type="text" id="input1" onclick="clearMe(this);" value="abcd" />
</span>
```

For a single line:

```
<input type="text" id="input1" onclick="this.value='';" value="abcd" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that there is a function [`document.clear()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.clear) which is actually called *instead* of yours!

In this case, you will also see a warning in Google Chrome because the function is deprecated:

> document.clear() is deprecated. This method doesn't do anything.
>   — Google Chrome v30

Choose another name:

```
function clearA(obj) {
  obj.value = "";
}

<input type="text" id="input1" onclick="clearA(this);" />
```

Or use real event listeners (which should be the preferred way!):

```
document.getElementById("input1").addEventListener("click", function () {
  this.value = "";
};
```