# Need to clear textfield I am writing on when I click on that text field

Tags: javascript, html

In a webpage I am writing I want to be able to clear two text boxes when I click on either one of them. So far I have been able to clear one when I click the other, but it won't clear itself.

Here is my html/javascript so far:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>


function clear()
{
 var c = document.getElementById('c');
 c.value = '';
 var f =document.getElementById('f');
 f.value= '';
}


</script>
</head>
<body>

<input placeholder = "Celsius" id="c" onclick='clear()'></br>
<input placeholder = "Fahrenheit" id="f" onclick='clear()'></br>

</body>
<p>

</p>
</html>
```

Comment: Try to rename function from `clear` to something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename your function `clear` to something else, otherwise you are calling the `document.clear` function

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165570/is-clear-a-reserved-word-in-javascript) by F. Kling might be useful to you