# clear() function not working with onClick, only through console

Tags: javascript, html

Hello there everyone,
I am helping a friend with JavaScript and there is an unusual problem. The `clear()` function used to clear the form page is not causing the objects on the page to clear when the button is clicked. It runs through console, though. What is the problem here? Here is the code for the site:

```html
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>UNDERTALE</title>
    <style>
        @font-face {
            font-family: Undertale;
            src: url("assets/DTM-Mono.otf") format("opentype");
        }
        body {
            font-family: Undertale;
            font-size: 24px;
            color: #FFFFFF;
        }

        table {
            font-family: Undertale;
            font-size: 24px;
            color: #FFFFFF;
        }
    </style> 
    <script>
        function validateCheckBox(){
            if(document.getElementsByName("check")[0].checked == true) { return true; }
            if(document.getElementsByName("check")[1].checked == true) { return true; }
            if(document.getElementsByName("check")[2].checked == true) { return true; }
            if(document.getElementsByName("check")[3].checked == true) { return true; }
            return false;
        }
        function validateDropdown(){
            if(document.getElementsByName("select")[0].selectedIndex == 0) { return false; }
            return true;
        }
        function validateRadio(){
            if(document.getElementsByName("radio")[0].checked == true) { return true; }
            if(document.getElementsByName("radio")[1].checked == true) { return true; }
            if(document.getElementsByName("radio")[2].checked == true) { return true; }
            if(document.getElementsByName("radio")[3].checked == true) { return true; }
            return false;
        }
        function validateTextArea(){
            if(document.getElementsByName("textarea")[0].value == "") { return false; }
                return true;
        }
        function submit(){
            if(validateCheckBox() == false) { alert("Please complete the first question."); return; }
            if(validateDropdown() == false) { alert("Please complete the second question."); return; }
            if(validateRadio() == false) { alert("Please complete the third question."); return; }
            if(validateTextArea() == false) { alert("Please complete the fourth question."); return; }
            alert("Form submitted successfully!");
        }
        function clear(){
            document.getElementsByName("check")[0].checked = false;
            document.getElementsByName("check")[1].checked = false;
            document.getElementsByName("check")[2].checked = false;
            document.getElementsByName("check")[3].checked = false;
            document.getElementsByName("select")[0].selectedIndex = 0;
            document.getElementsByName("radio")[0].checked = false;
            document.getElementsByName("radio")[1].checked = false;
            document.getElementsByName("radio")[2].checked = false;
            document.getElementsByName("radio")[3].checked = false;
            document.getElementsByName("textarea")[0].value = "";
            return;
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body bgcolor="#000000">
        <center>
            <table width="1000px">
            <tr><td>
            <center>
                <img src="assets/feedback.png" width="700px">
            </center>
            <tr><td>
            <br>
            <center>
                1. What did you find helpful on this website?<br>
                <input type="checkbox" name="check">About</input>
                <input type="checkbox" name="check">Story</input>
                <input type="checkbox" name="check">Main Characters</input>
                <input type="checkbox" name="check">Locations</input>
                <br><br>
                2. Which page should I add more information?<br>
                <select name="select">
                    <option>
                    <option>About
                    <option>Story
                    <option>Main Characters
                    <option>Locations
                    <option>None
                </select>
                <br><br>
                3. Which page did you find the most helpful?<br>
                <input type="radio" name="radio">About</input>
                <input type="radio" name="radio">Story</input>
                <input type="radio" name="radio">Main Characters</input>
                <input type="radio" name="radio">Locations</input><br><br>
                4. Please leave any other comments about this website here.<br>
                <textarea rows=10 cols=50 name="textarea"></textarea><br><br>
                <button onclick="submit()">Submit</button>
                <button onclick="clear()">Clear</button>
            </center>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<button type="reset" value="Clear">Clear</button>` use this.

Comment: We tried that before, and no luck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the function name for `clear()` with another name, e.g. `reset()` or better yet, use the built-in reset functionality as pointed out by [Hamza Zafeer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37691982/1647737).

Why do you need to rename `clear()`? Because a function `clear()` is already defined within inline event-handlers. See [Is "clear" a reserved word in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165570/is-clear-a-reserved-word-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks for helping me out... :)

Answer (score 1):

```html
<form>
    Your Name:<input type="text">
    <button type="submit" value ="Submit">Submit</button>
    <button type="reset" value ="Clear">Clear</button>
  </form>
```

```
<button type="reset" value="Clear">Clear</button>
```

Use This and Also start Form tag `<form>`and end Form tag `</form>` . Then This Clear Button works.

Also Close your `<option>` like this `</option>`

Answer (score 1):

try to add an id to your clear button and attach an event

```
 document.getElementById("btnClear").addEventListener("click", clear);


<button id="btnClear">Clear</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Clear()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console/clear) by itself just clears the console. A quick search of [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/search?q=clear%28%29) and you can see that it is also depreciated method of the document.

try instead to use [location.reload()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload)