# button onclick wont call the javascript function

Tags: javascript

I am calling a function on a button click. But the function is not getting called. I dont know what I am doing wrong. Please help.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function clear() {
      document.getElementById('inp').value = "";
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="inp" name="">
  <input type="button" onclick="clear()">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: clear() is javascript reserve word

Comment: @NewbeeDev no its not. It just call `document.clear` instead. I have shared a reference link in my answer. You can check it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`clear` is not a reserved word but its calling `document.clear` instead. Try updating name of function

#### Sample

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function clear1() {
      document.getElementById('inp').value = "";
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="inp" name="">
  <input type="button" onclick="clear1()">
</body>
</html>
```

#### Sample - Override document.clear

**Note:** its a bad practice to override `document/window/prototype` functions. This is just for demonstration purpose.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function clear1() {
      document.getElementById('inp').value = "";
    }
    document.clear = function(){
      console.log('My clear function')
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="inp" name="">
  <input type="button" onclick="clear()">
</body>
</html>
```

#### Reference

[Is “clear” a reserved word in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165570/is-clear-a-reserved-word-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Change the function name because clear function make that issue. make the function name clearInput or what ever you convenient

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function clearTxtBox() {
      document.getElementById('inp').value = "";
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <input type="text" id="inp" name="">
  <input type="button" onclick="clearTxtBox()">
</body>
</html>
```

Just change your function name and it will work.