# html button won't call function

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to call a function called "clear()" in javascript but it won't work, the function works when put into the console but won't when I click the button.

Comment: add the full code

Comment: You want to show a [MCVE] that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: Generally when asking "why doesn't this code work" it's a good idea to show said code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a problem with your function name, try change it to `clearMe()`

Use the link below, the code works fine..

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onclick

..if you change the function name to `clear` it does not.

Comment: Thought it might have been a reserved word in javascript, doesn't look to be but looks like it still causes issues.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165570/is-clear-a-reserved-word-in-javascript

Comment: No problem, glad it helped!