# Creating a clear button using Javascript and HTML

Tags: javascript, html

Firstly, I know this question has been asked before on here - I have looked at those answers but for some reason it is not working for me at all!

I have a variety of text fields for which I would like to have a 'clear' button to empty the value of the field when clicked.

This is my JavaScript:

```
function clear() {
    document.getElementById("customerName").value="";
}
```

and my HTML for this is...

```
<table border="1" id="orderForm">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">Customer Details</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="font">Customer Name</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="customerName"></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<button type="button" id="button1" onClick="clear()">Clear</button>
```

I have no idea why it won't work, and I've been trying to get it work for ages.

Comment: Try changing your function name.


Check this  [Is “clear” a reserved word in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165570/is-clear-a-reserved-word-in-javascript)

Comment: This is correct!  Can't believe it was as simple as that.  Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`clear()` is generally not a good function name to define. It conflicts with document.clear.

Also remember you can always just use `<input type="reset" value="clear"/>` which might be even simpler! :)

```js
function clearIt() {
 document.getElementById('customerName').value = "";
}
```

```html
<table border="1" id="orderForm">
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Customer Details</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="font">Customer Name</td>
    <td><input type="text" id="customerName"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<button type="button" id="button1" onClick="clearIt()">Clear</button>
```

Comment: Edited slightly to accommodate @sweaver2112 's very useful info about `document.clear`

Answer (score 0):

As @Pratyush already mentioned, change function name to something else - your code will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, `clear()` **is** perfectly valid Vanilla Javascript.

It just so happens that `document` defines a `clear()` also:

[image]

...and since your ***HTML attribute assigned click handler*** gets executed with a modified scope chain, the `document` object's `clear()` comes before your global function in the scope chain (from Javascript: The Definitive Guide):

> Event handlers registered as HTML attributes are a special case,
>   however. They are converted into top-level functions that have access
>   to global variables but not to any local variables. But, for
>   historical reasons, they run with a modified scope chain. Event
>   handlers defined by HTML attributes can use the properties of the
>   target object, the containing  object (if there is one), and the
>   Document object as if they are local variables.

and then he discusses your exact case:

> the modified scope chain of HTML event handlers is a source of
>   pitfalls, since the properties of each of the objects in the chain
>   shadow any properties of the same name in the global object. The
>   Document object defines a (rarely used) open() method, for example, so
>   an HTML event handler that wants to invoke the open() method of the
>   Window object must explicitly write window.open instead of open

so, your function could be reached via `window.clear()` in the HTML:

```js
function clear() {    document.getElementById("customerName").value="";
}
```

```html
<table border="1" id="orderForm">
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">Customer Details</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td id="font">Customer Name</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="customerName"></td>
    </tr>
</table>

<button type="button" id="button1" onClick="window.clear()">Clear</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

First call jquery library and then do the following code instead of yours one

```
$document.ready(function(){
$("button1").click(function(){
document.getElementById("#customerName").value="";
});
});
```

I prefer to put all javascript before the end of body tag.