# jQuery Set Dropdown to Blank Value

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some reason I'm having trouble selecting an existing blank value in a dropdown with jQuery. The blank option exists, but setting it via `$('#studyList option[value=""]').prop('selected', 'selected');` does not work (nor does `.prop('selected', true)`). Am I doing something wrong?

```js
$('#studyList').append(
          $('<option value="155" selected="selected">Study 1</option>'));
$('#studyList').append(
          $('<option value="157">Study 2</option>'));
        
$('#studyList').prepend("<option value='' ></option>");

function clear() {
   $('#studyList option[value=""]').prop('selected', 'selected');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="studyList"></select>

<button id="clear" onclick="clear();" value="Clear">Clear</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Name your function something other than `clear` as it conflicts with a [built-in function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165570/is-clear-a-reserved-word-in-javascript)

```js
$('#studyList').append(
          $('<option value="155" selected="selected">Study 1</option>'));
$('#studyList').append(
          $('<option value="157">Study 2</option>'));
        
$('#studyList').prepend("<option value='' ></option>");

function xclear() {
   $('#studyList option[value=""]').prop('selected', 'selected');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="studyList"></select>

<button id="clear" onclick="xclear();" value="Clear">Clear</button>
```

Also, as others have mentioned, you could also just set the value of the select with `$('#studylist').val('')`

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#studyList').append(
  '<option value="155" selected="selected">Study 1</option>'
);
$('#studyList').append(
  '<option value="157">Study 2</option>'
);

$('#studyList').prepend("<option value='' ></option>");

$('#clear').on('click', function () {
  $('#studyList').val('');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="studyList"></select>

<button id="clear" value="Clear">Clear</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("#studyList").val("");
```