# Clear Canvas not working

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I have a basic page with a canvas. In Javascript I run a function after pressing a button that changes the background color and draws a basic rect shape.

I have a second button though that uses another JS function in order to clean the canvas but it doesn't work.

```
function clear() {
  var c = document.getElementById("can1");
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");

  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
  c.style.backgroundColor = white;
}
```

I have also a codepen-link so that you can see the whole code.
[Codepen page](https://codepen.io/TsigkrosNikos/pen/PQrgbQ)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Renaming the function will do the trick.

When you are calling to `clear()` function in the onclick event, you will be executing `document.clear()`.

You can take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165570/is-clear-a-reserved-word-in-javascript?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) for more answers.

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't know that. I named the function with a different name such as `clean()` and it runs perfectly.