# Why i can not control setinterval and clearinterval javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

When test code it's will `setinterval` by not to click and when i click `<div onclick="clear()">CLEAR</div>` it's not `clearinterval` too.

How can i do for setinterval when click `<div onclick="test_fn()">TEST</div>`
and clearinterval when click `<div onclick="clear()">CLEAR</div>`

```html
<div onclick="test_fn()">TEST</div>

<script>
var xxx = null;
xxx = window.setInterval(function test_fn(){
 test_xxx();
}, 5000);



function test_xxx(){
 alert("123456789");
}
</script>

<br>
<div onclick="clear()">CLEAR</div>

<script>function clear(){
 window.clearInterval(xxx);
}
</script>
```

Comment: look at the error in the console ... note `test_fn` is not a global function, therefore not visible to `onclick=`

Comment: console show `test_fn is not defined`

Comment: try a different name for function `clear` - seems the browser doesn't like that (any other names seems to work)

Comment: that's why clicking test does nothing - but - the interval is started immediately anyway

Comment: i change function name to  `clear_xx` it's work good for `clearinterval` but still error when `setinterval`

Comment: because you're trying to call a function that **does not exist**

Comment: i have to set function `test_fn` to global ?

Comment: if you want an `onclick` attribute to access it, then yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Put the logic for `setInterval()` in the `onclick` handler rather
  than outside of it.
- Also change the `clear()` to any other name. As you are invoking document.clear() instead of your function.
  [Is "clear" a reserved word in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165570/is-clear-a-reserved-word-in-javascript)
- You can use fat arrow syntax `=>` of ES6 to pass the callback
  function to `setInterval()`.

```html
<div onclick="test_fn()">TEST</div>
<br>
<div onclick="clear_fn()">CLEAR</div>

<script>
var xxx = null;
function test_fn(){
    alert('clicked');
    xxx = window.setInterval(() => {
     test_xxx();
   }, 5000);
}
function clear_fn(){
   alert('cleared')
   window.clearInterval(xxx);
}
function test_xxx(){
 alert("123456789");
}
</script>
```