# Having Trouble With JavaScript Location Reload

Tags: javascript

I'm creating my first JavaScript calculator, and I thought I could cheat on the clear button by reloading the page, but it doesn't seem to work. I have tried online editors, reopening chrome, moving files, and it still doesn't seem to work I don't know why, but help would be greatly appreciated.
EDIT: Sorry for taking so long, as you can see I now have the HTML and CSS to go with the JavaScript

```js
var firstNumber = [];
var secondNumber = [];
let current = 'firstNumber';
var operation;

function clear(){
    location.reload();
}

function set(number){
    if (current == 'firstNumber'){
        firstNumber.push(number);
    }
    else{
        secondNumber.push(number);
    }
    document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = number;
}

function change(operator){
    current = 'secondNumber';
    operation = operator;
    if (operation == 'addition'){
        return document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = '+';
    }
    else if (operation == 'subtraction'){
        return document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = "-";
    }
    else if (operator == 'multiplication'){
        return document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = 'x';
    }
    else if (operator == 'multiplication'){
    }
    return document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = '÷';
}

function solve(){
    firstNumber = firstNumber.join('');
    secondNumber = secondNumber.join('');
    firstNumber = parseInt(firstNumber);
    secondNumber = parseInt(secondNumber);
    if (operation == 'addition'){
        return document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = firstNumber + secondNumber;
    }
    else if (operation == 'subtraction'){
        return document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = firstNumber - secondNumber;
    }
    else if (operation == 'multiplication'){
        return document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = firstNumber * secondNumber;
    }
    else if (operation == 'division'){
        return document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = firstNumber / secondNumber;
    }
}

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```css
h1{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 75px;
    text-shadow: 3px 3px 15px red;
}

#container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 50%;
    height: 500px;
    margin-left: 25%;
}

.row{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    height: 15%;
    margin-top: 1%;
    width: 100%;
}

button{
    width: 30%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 5px;
    font-size: 35px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
    border-color: purple;
}

#answer{
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: red;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 95%;
    height: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#wide{
    width: 95%;
    height: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

body{
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgb(0, 0, 255), rgb(100, 0, 255));
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Calculator</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/calculator.css">
        <script src="/static/calculator.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Calculator</h1>
        <br />
        <div id="container">
            <p id="answer"></p>
            <button onclick="solve()" id="wide">=</button>
            <div class="row">
                <button onclick="set(1)">1</button>
                <button onclick="set(2)">2</button>
                <button onclick="set(3)">3</button>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <button onclick="set(4)">4</button>
                <button onclick="set(5)">5</button>
                <button onclick="set(6)">6</button>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <button onclick="set(7)">7</button>
                <button onclick="set(8)">8</button>
                <button onclick="set(9)">9</button>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <button onclick="set(0)">0</button>
                <button onclick="change('addition')">+</button>
                <button onclick="change('subtraction')">-</button>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <button onclick="change('multiplication')">x</button>
                <button onclick="change('division')">/</button>
                <button onclick="clear()">c</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: is your `clear` method being called  ? showing you html code would be more useful

Comment: Check if your clear method is being called by adding a debug statement in it.
Where is the code that is calling the clear function

Comment: Use a service such as [Codepen](http://codepen.io), [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or [REPL.it](http://repl.it) to post your full code so that we can see, and experience, the code.

Comment: showing your form would help.

Comment: if you are trying to clear answer, why not just do it the same way you set it?  `document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = 0`  in the `clear()` function? This may not be possible based on the rest of your code or goals, but as others have stated, this question is unclear due to lack of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that clear() requires to bind an event listener in the DOM, for example:

```
<button id="clear">c</button>
<script>document.getElementById("clear").addEventListener("click", clear);</script>
```

Or, alternatively, use **document.clear()** (deprecated) or **window.clear()**.

See related question:

[Is "clear" a reserved word in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165570/is-clear-a-reserved-word-in-javascript)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/clear

To avoid that, simply rename clear() function to clearResult() and it will work.

See modified snippet below.

In addition, instead of **location.reload();** you can simply clear content of the answer as a faster alternative:

```
document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = '';
```

```js
var firstNumber = [];
var secondNumber = [];
let current = 'firstNumber';
var operation;

function clearResult(){
    location.reload();
}

function set(number){
    if (current == 'firstNumber'){
        firstNumber.push(number);
    }
    else{
        secondNumber.push(number);
    }
    document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = number;
}

function change(operator){
    current = 'secondNumber';
    operation = operator;
    if (operation == 'addition'){
        return document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = '+';
    }
    else if (operation == 'subtraction'){
        return document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = "-";
    }
    else if (operator == 'multiplication'){
        return document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = 'x';
    }
    else if (operator == 'multiplication'){
    }
    return document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = '÷';
}

function solve(){
    firstNumber = firstNumber.join('');
    secondNumber = secondNumber.join('');
    firstNumber = parseInt(firstNumber);
    secondNumber = parseInt(secondNumber);
    if (operation == 'addition'){
        return document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = firstNumber + secondNumber;
    }
    else if (operation == 'subtraction'){
        return document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = firstNumber - secondNumber;
    }
    else if (operation == 'multiplication'){
        return document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = firstNumber * secondNumber;
    }
    else if (operation == 'division'){
        return document.getElementById('answer').innerHTML = firstNumber / secondNumber;
    }
}

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```css
h1{
    text-align: center;
    font-family: monospace;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 75px;
    text-shadow: 3px 3px 15px red;
}

#container{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 50%;
    height: 500px;
    margin-left: 25%;
}

.row{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    height: 15%;
    margin-top: 1%;
    width: 100%;
}

button{
    width: 30%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 5px;
    font-size: 35px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
    border-color: purple;
}

#answer{
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: red;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 95%;
    height: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#wide{
    width: 95%;
    height: 35px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

body{
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, rgb(0, 0, 255), rgb(100, 0, 255));
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Calculator</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/calculator.css">
        <script src="/static/calculator.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Calculator</h1>
        <br />
        <div id="container">
            <p id="answer"></p>
            <button onclick="solve()" id="wide">=</button>
            <div class="row">
                <button onclick="set(1)">1</button>
                <button onclick="set(2)">2</button>
                <button onclick="set(3)">3</button>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <button onclick="set(4)">4</button>
                <button onclick="set(5)">5</button>
                <button onclick="set(6)">6</button>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <button onclick="set(7)">7</button>
                <button onclick="set(8)">8</button>
                <button onclick="set(9)">9</button>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <button onclick="set(0)">0</button>
                <button onclick="change('addition')">+</button>
                <button onclick="change('subtraction')">-</button>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <button onclick="change('multiplication')">x</button>
                <button onclick="change('division')">/</button>
                <button onclick="clearResult()">c</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```