# Html button fails to fire event function with same name as Document.clear

Tags: javascript, html, button, dom-events

I have been playing around with a map building tool. I started separating out some of the higher functions (e.g. draw, grow, seed) into separate buttons. All the buttons work except clear. The clear button is supposed to fire an event to the clear function, but it doesn't. The button click is caught by a breakpoint, but the clear function won't work. I tried calling different functions from the clear button and they all worked. I can write sequences of javascript like "grow(); draw();" and it works. I even created a new function "other" just to redirect to the clear function. Unbelievably that worked. I have no idea why my code will not let me call the clear function from the clear button.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      canvas {background-color:black;}
    </style>
    <script>
      var dim = 400;
      var pixel = 1;
      var heights;
      var colors;
      var ctx;

      function loadAll()
      {
        var can = document.getElementById("map");
        ctx = can.getContext("2d");
        can.style.width = (dim*pixel)+"px";
        can.style.height = (dim*pixel)+"px";
        can.width=dim*pixel;
        can.height=dim*pixel;

        colors = new Object();
        for(let i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
          colors[i]="rgb("+(25+i*25)+","+(25+i*25)+",255)"
        }

        for(let i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
          colors[i+5]="rgb("+(255-(i*5))+","+(255-(i*12))+","+(170-(i*20))+")"
        }

        for(let i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
          colors[i+10]="rgb("+(185-(i*24))+","+(218-(i*11))+","+(69-(i*6))+")"
        }

        for(let i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
          colors[i+15]="rgb("+(153+(i*20))+","+125+","+45+")"
        }

        for(let i=0;i<5;i++)
        { 
          colors[i+20]="rgb("+(153+(i*4))+","+(125-(i*18))+","+(45+(i*4))+")"
        }

        for(let i=0;i<5;i++)
        { 
          colors[i+20]="rgb("+(171+(i*4))+","+(34+(i*32))+","+(27+(i*33))+")"
        }

        colors[5]="rgb(150,150,250)";
        clear();
        draw();
      }

      function other()
      {
        clear();
      }

      function clear()
      {
        heights = new Array(dim);
        for(let i=0;i<dim;i++)
        {
          heights[i]=new Array(dim);
          for(let y=0;y<dim;y++)
          {
            heights[i][y]=0;
          }
        }
        draw();
      }

      function seed()
      {
        clear();
        var fill=.01;
        for(let x=0;x<dim;x++)
        {
          for(let y=0;y<dim;y++)
          {
            var r = Math.random();
            if(r>(1-fill))
            {
              heights[x][y]=1;
            }
            else if(r<fill)
            {
              heights[x][y]=-1;
            }
            else
            {
              heights[x][y]=0;
            }
          }
        }

        draw();
      }

      function grow(variability)
      {
        next = new Array(dim);
        for(let x=0;x<dim;x++)
        {
          next[x]=new Array(dim);
          for(let y=0;y<dim;y++)
          {
            next[x][y]=0;
          }
        }

        for(let x=0;x<dim;x++)
        {
          for(let y=0;y<dim;y++)
          {
            if(heights[x][y]==0)
            {
              continue;
            }

            next[x][y]+=heights[x][y];
            var dir=0;

            if(next[x][y]>0)
            {
              next[x][y]+=1;
              dir=1;
            }

            if(next[x][y]<0)
            {
              next[x][y]-=1;
              dir=-.5;
            }

            if(x>0)
            {
              if(y>0 && heights[x-1][y-1]==0 && Math.random()<variability)
              {
                next[x-1][y-1]+=dir;
              }

              if(y<dim-1 && heights[x-1][y+1]==0 && Math.random()<variability)
              {
                next[x-1][y+1]+=dir;
              }

              if(heights[x-1][y]==0 && Math.random()>variability)
              {
                next[x-1][y]+=dir;
              }
            }

            if(x<dim-1)
            {
              if(y>0 && heights[x+1][y-1]==0 && Math.random()<variability)
              {
                next[x+1][y-1]+=dir;
              }

              if(y<dim-1 && heights[x+1][y+1]==0 && Math.random()<variability)
              {
                next[x+1][y+1]+=dir;
              }

              if(heights[x+1][y]==0 && Math.random()>variability)
              {
                next[x+1][y]+=dir;
              }
            }

            if(y>0 && heights[x][y-1]==0 && Math.random()>variability)
            {
              next[x][y-1]+=dir;
            }

            if(y<dim-1 && heights[x][y+1]==0 && Math.random()>variability)
            {
              next[x][y+1]+=dir;
            }

            //maximums
            if(next[x][y]<-5)
            {
              next[x][y]=-5;
            }

            if(next[x][y]>20)
            {
              next[x][y]=20;
            }

            if(next[x][y]!=heights[x][y])
            {
              var a=0;
            }
          }
        }

        heights=next;
      }

      function draw()
      {
        for(let x=0;x<dim;x++)
        {
          for(let y=0;y<dim;y++)
          {
            ctx.fillStyle = colors[heights[x][y]+5];
            ctx.fillRect(x*pixel,y*pixel, pixel, pixel);
          }
        }
      }

      var dragType = 0;

      function drag(e)
      {
        x=e.layerX;
        y=e.layerY;
        output.innerHTML="(x,y): ("+x+", "+y+") Type: "+dragType+" @ "+heights[x][y];
        if(dragType==0)
        {
          return;
        }
        heights[x][y]+=dragType;
      }

      function down(e)
      {
        if(e.button==0)
        {
          dragType=1;
        }
        else
        {
          dragType=-1;
        }
        x=e.layerX;
        y=e.layerY;
        output.innerHTML="(x,y): ("+x+", "+y+") Type: "+dragType+" @ "+heights[x][y];
      }

      function up(e)
      {
        dragType=0;
        x=e.layerX;
        y=e.layerY;
        output.innerHTML="(x,y): ("+x+", "+y+") Type: "+dragType+" @ "+heights[x][y];
        draw();
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="loadAll()">
    <button onclick="other()">Clear</button>
    <button onclick="seed()">Seed</button>
    <button onclick="grow(.85); draw();">Grow</button>
    <button onclick="grow(.85)">Grow ONLY</button>
    <button onclick="draw()">Draw</button><br>
    <canvas id="map" onmousemove="drag(event)" onmousedown="down(event)" onmouseup="up(event)"></canvas><br>
    <p id="output"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you share some sort of output, does it throw an error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the issue is it's calling the **document.clear()** function instead of the clear function you have created.

Since you are trying to access it from the DOM Event it is calling the **document.clear()** function.

To solve this, you can use **window.clear()** or whatever scope you are in to properly call the clear method.

You can find some more information here:
[Is "clear" a reserved word in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165570/is-clear-a-reserved-word-in-javascript)

Comment: Everyone did a good job explaining something I should have already known, but @sylens gets the “right” answer for being most complete and having a useful reference. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is the word `Clear`. I believe javascript thinks the word `clear` means a key or reserved word. I tried changing the function word `Clear` to `Cleared` in your code and the code worked fine.

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      canvas {background-color:black;}
    </style>
    <script>
      var dim = 400;
      var pixel = 1;
      var heights;
      var colors;
      var ctx;

      function loadAll()
      {
        var can = document.getElementById("map");
        ctx = can.getContext("2d");
        can.style.width = (dim*pixel)+"px";
        can.style.height = (dim*pixel)+"px";
        can.width=dim*pixel;
        can.height=dim*pixel;

        colors = new Object();
        for(let i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
          colors[i]="rgb("+(25+i*25)+","+(25+i*25)+",255)"
        }

        for(let i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
          colors[i+5]="rgb("+(255-(i*5))+","+(255-(i*12))+","+(170-(i*20))+")"
        }

        for(let i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
          colors[i+10]="rgb("+(185-(i*24))+","+(218-(i*11))+","+(69-(i*6))+")"
        }

        for(let i=0;i<5;i++)
        {
          colors[i+15]="rgb("+(153+(i*20))+","+125+","+45+")"
        }

        for(let i=0;i<5;i++)
        { 
          colors[i+20]="rgb("+(153+(i*4))+","+(125-(i*18))+","+(45+(i*4))+")"
        }

        for(let i=0;i<5;i++)
        { 
          colors[i+20]="rgb("+(171+(i*4))+","+(34+(i*32))+","+(27+(i*33))+")"
        }

        colors[5]="rgb(150,150,250)";
        cleared();
        draw();
      }

      function other()
      {
        cleared();
      }

      function cleared()
      {
        heights = new Array(dim);
        for(let i=0;i<dim;i++)
        {
          heights[i]=new Array(dim);
          for(let y=0;y<dim;y++)
          {
            heights[i][y]=0;
          }
        }
        draw();
      }

      function seed()
      {
        cleared();
        var fill=.01;
        for(let x=0;x<dim;x++)
        {
          for(let y=0;y<dim;y++)
          {
            var r = Math.random();
            if(r>(1-fill))
            {
              heights[x][y]=1;
            }
            else if(r<fill)
            {
              heights[x][y]=-1;
            }
            else
            {
              heights[x][y]=0;
            }
          }
        }

        draw();
      }

      function grow(variability)
      {
        next = new Array(dim);
        for(let x=0;x<dim;x++)
        {
          next[x]=new Array(dim);
          for(let y=0;y<dim;y++)
          {
            next[x][y]=0;
          }
        }

        for(let x=0;x<dim;x++)
        {
          for(let y=0;y<dim;y++)
          {
            if(heights[x][y]==0)
            {
              continue;
            }

            next[x][y]+=heights[x][y];
            var dir=0;

            if(next[x][y]>0)
            {
              next[x][y]+=1;
              dir=1;
            }

            if(next[x][y]<0)
            {
              next[x][y]-=1;
              dir=-.5;
            }

            if(x>0)
            {
              if(y>0 && heights[x-1][y-1]==0 && Math.random()<variability)
              {
                next[x-1][y-1]+=dir;
              }

              if(y<dim-1 && heights[x-1][y+1]==0 && Math.random()<variability)
              {
                next[x-1][y+1]+=dir;
              }

              if(heights[x-1][y]==0 && Math.random()>variability)
              {
                next[x-1][y]+=dir;
              }
            }

            if(x<dim-1)
            {
              if(y>0 && heights[x+1][y-1]==0 && Math.random()<variability)
              {
                next[x+1][y-1]+=dir;
              }

              if(y<dim-1 && heights[x+1][y+1]==0 && Math.random()<variability)
              {
                next[x+1][y+1]+=dir;
              }

              if(heights[x+1][y]==0 && Math.random()>variability)
              {
                next[x+1][y]+=dir;
              }
            }

            if(y>0 && heights[x][y-1]==0 && Math.random()>variability)
            {
              next[x][y-1]+=dir;
            }

            if(y<dim-1 && heights[x][y+1]==0 && Math.random()>variability)
            {
              next[x][y+1]+=dir;
            }

            //maximums
            if(next[x][y]<-5)
            {
              next[x][y]=-5;
            }

            if(next[x][y]>20)
            {
              next[x][y]=20;
            }

            if(next[x][y]!=heights[x][y])
            {
              var a=0;
            }
          }
        }

        heights=next;
      }

      function draw()
      {
        for(let x=0;x<dim;x++)
        {
          for(let y=0;y<dim;y++)
          {
            ctx.fillStyle = colors[heights[x][y]+5];
            ctx.fillRect(x*pixel,y*pixel, pixel, pixel);
          }
        }
      }

      var dragType = 0;

      function drag(e)
      {
        x=e.layerX;
        y=e.layerY;
        output.innerHTML="(x,y): ("+x+", "+y+") Type: "+dragType+" @ "+heights[x][y];
        if(dragType==0)
        {
          return;
        }
        heights[x][y]+=dragType;
      }

      function down(e)
      {
        if(e.button==0)
        {
          dragType=1;
        }
        else
        {
          dragType=-1;
        }
        x=e.layerX;
        y=e.layerY;
        output.innerHTML="(x,y): ("+x+", "+y+") Type: "+dragType+" @ "+heights[x][y];
      }

      function up(e)
      {
        dragType=0;
        x=e.layerX;
        y=e.layerY;
        output.innerHTML="(x,y): ("+x+", "+y+") Type: "+dragType+" @ "+heights[x][y];
        draw();
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="loadAll()">
    <button onclick="cleared()">Clear</button>
    <button onclick="seed()">Seed</button>
    <button onclick="grow(.85); draw();">Grow</button>
    <button onclick="grow(.85)">Grow ONLY</button>
    <button onclick="draw()">Draw</button><br>
    <canvas id="map" onmousemove="drag(event)" onmousedown="down(event)" onmouseup="up(event)"></canvas><br>
    <p id="output"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I changed the function name from clear() to clearmap() and it seems to be working fine now.

It might be interfering with document.clear()?