# How do I clear on button click

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
display = document.getElementById('outputDiv');
display.innerHTML = 'Your Number Is: ';

function clear() {
  document.getElementById("outputDiv").innerHTML = "";
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="calculator()">

<input type="reset" value="Clear" onclick="clear()">

<div id="outputDiv"></div>
```

On the reset button clicked, I would like to erase display.innerHTML='Your Number Is: ' + total;

Comment: what is the issue? doesn't your code working?

Comment: I just pasted a part of the code in the website because it won't let me paste the too much in. I have a the math on top of display=. After it printed total. I have a button that is the reset button I want to erase the text that it displayed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is "clear" a reserved word in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165570/is-clear-a-reserved-word-in-javascript)

Answer (score 8):

Do not use `clear` as your function name, because due to the inline event listeners' scope, it confuses with the deprecated [**`Document.clear()`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/clear).

Try some other name:

```html
<input type="reset" value="Clear" onclick = "clearValue()">

<div id="outputDiv"></div>
<script>

  var display = document.getElementById('outputDiv');
  var total = 500;
  display.innerHTML='Your Number Is: ' + total;

  function clearValue() {
    display.innerHTML = "";
  }
</script>
```

**More:** [Is “clear” a reserved word in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165570/is-clear-a-reserved-word-in-javascript)

Comment: `clear` **is not a reserved word!!!** [Reserved keywords list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Keywords)

Comment: @FZs, I have updated the answer with a link, thanks:)

Comment: While it's not a reserved keyword, it's a method of the document object, and the document object is in the function handler scope, before the window object, which explains the issue. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165570/is-clear-a-reserved-word-in-javascript