# can't use clearInterval

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

in trying to create a page that will show the current time which will refresh every x seconds - x is a user input
i use setInterval and clearInterval but it looks like the clearInterval doesn't have any effect at all :(
here's the code:

```
 <script>
      let changeTime = () => {
        let secs = document.getElementById("sec").value * 1000;
        clearInterval(timer);
        let timer = setInterval(() => {
          let d = new Date();
          document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = d.toLocaleString();
          console.log(secs);
        }, secs);
      };

      function clear() {
        clearInterval(timer);
      }

      //both functions are called with an onChange event
```

thanks!

Comment: `clear` doesn't have access to the `timer` variable

Answer (score 1):

Your `timer` variable is local to your `changeTime()` function. Declare it outside the function.

```
  let timer;
  let changeTime = () => {
    let secs = document.getElementById("sec").value * 1000;
    clearInterval(timer);
    timer = setInterval(() => {
      let d = new Date();
      document.getElementById("example").innerHTML = d.toLocaleString();
      console.log(secs);
    }, secs);
  };
```

When the variable is local to the function, it only exists during the time a function call is happening, and a new instance of the variable is created on each call. By declaring it *outside* the function, the variable and its value persists.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `let` declares a variables as local, and so `timer` is not visible to `clear()`. Just remove `let` (and don't add anything else), and the variable is declared as global.

Second, although `clear` is not a reserved JavaScript word, it actually calls the obsolete `document.clear()`.

> [Is "clear" a reserved word in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7165570/is-clear-a-reserved-word-in-javascript)

So either change it's name or use `window` or `self` to remove the ambiguity.

```js
let changeTime = () => {
    let secs = 100;
    timer = setInterval(() => {
        let d = new Date();
        document.getElementById("out").innerHTML = d.toLocaleString();
        }, secs);
      };

function clear() {
    clearInterval(timer);
    }

changeTime();
 </script>
```

```html
<span id="out"></span>
<button onclick="self.clear();">clear</button>
```

Comment: I found on mdn that document.clear() is no longer supported by most browser. anyway, I'll remember not to use it to prevent any problems. Thanks!